# Error: 500 Exception serializing request! when trying to use HTTP

Tags: python, http, raspberry-pi, pycharm

I have been trying to have a STT code send the text it transcribes into my Raspberry Pi 4 B using HTTP. I had a few code errors when testing, but later, after fixing them all, I get the message:

> Error: 500 Exception serializing request!

in the Pycharm console when running the code. The Raspberry Pi doesn't give any errors.

I'll post both codes and the text in the consoles if it helps, but I can't find much online about this specific error.

```py
import queue
import re
import sys
import os
from google.cloud import speech
import pyaudio
import requests

# Set your Google Cloud Speech API credentials
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "C://Users//danim//OneDrive//Desktop//programming//workpls-401909-66721bf5ced8.json"

# Audio recording parameters
RATE = 48000
CHUNK = int(RATE / 10)  # 100ms

class MicrophoneStream:
    """Opens a recording stream as a generator yielding the audio chunks."""

    def __init__(self: object, rate: int = RATE, chunk: int = CHUNK) -> None:
        """The audio -- and generator -- is guaranteed to be on the main thread."""
        self._rate = rate
        self._chunk = chunk

        # Create a thread-safe buffer of audio data
        self._buff = queue.Queue()
        self.closed = True

    def __enter__(self: object) -> object:
        self._audio_interface = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self._audio_stream = self._audio_interface.open(
            format=pyaudio.paInt16,
            channels=1,
            rate=self._rate,
            input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=self._chunk,
            stream_callback=self._fill_buffer,
        )

        self.closed = False

        return self

    def __exit__(
            self: object,
            type: object,
            value: object,
            traceback: object,
    ) -> None:
        self._audio_stream.stop_stream()
        self._audio_stream.close()
        self.closed = True
        self._buff.put(None)
        self._audio_interface.terminate()

    def _fill_buffer(
            self: object,
            in_data: object,
            frame_count: int,
            time_info: object,
            status_flags: object,
    ) -> object:
        self._buff.put(in_data)
        return None, pyaudio.paContinue

    def generator(self: object) -> object:
        while not self.closed:
            chunk = self._buff.get()
            if chunk is None:
                return
            data = [chunk]

            while True:
                try:
                    chunk = self._buff.get(block=False)
                    if chunk is None:
                        return
                    data.append(chunk)
                except queue.Empty:
                    break

            yield b"".join(data)

def send_location_to_pi(location):
    pi_url = 'http://<192.168.1.128>:8080/location'  # Replace with your Raspberry Pi's IP
    data = {'location': location}

    response = requests.post(pi_url, json=data)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Location sent to Pi successfully.")
    else:
        print("Failed to send location to Pi.")


def listen_print_loop(responses: object) -> str:
    num_chars_printed = 0
    for response in responses:
        if not response.results:
            continue

        result = response.results[0]
        if not result.alternatives:
            continue

        transcript = result.alternatives[0].transcript

        overwrite_chars = " " * (num_chars_printed - len(transcript))

        if not result.is_final:
            sys.stdout.write(transcript + overwrite_chars + "\r")
            sys.stdout.flush()
            num_chars_printed = len(transcript)
        else:
            print(transcript + overwrite_chars)

            if re.search(r"\b(exit|quit)\b", transcript, re.I):
                print("Exiting..")
                break

            num_chars_printed = 0

        # Send the recognized location to the Raspberry Pi
        send_location_to_pi(transcript)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        audio_client = speech.SpeechClient()
        config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
            encoding=speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
            sample_rate_hertz=RATE,
            language_code='en-US',
        )

        with MicrophoneStream(RATE, CHUNK) as stream:
            audio_generator = stream.generator()
            requests = (
                stream.StreamingRecognizeRequest(audio_content=content, location=transcript)
                for content in audio_generator
            )

            responses = audio_client.streaming_recognize(config=config, requests=requests)

            listen_print_loop(responses)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
```

Response:

> C:\Users\danim\PycharmProjects\EXAM\venv\Scripts\python.exe
> C:\Users\danim\OneDrive\Desktop\programming\STT.py
> Error: 500 Exception serializing request!
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

For the Pi

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import requests
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

# Function to store the received location
current_location = 'Tarragona'  # Set an initial location

@app.route('/location', methods=['POST'])
def receive_location():
    data = request.get_json()
    location = data.get('location')

    if location:
        # Store the received location for use in the weather retrieval
        global current_location
        current_location = location
        return 'Location received and stored successfully', 200
    else:
        return 'Invalid location data', 400

# Function to get weather info for a location
def get_weather(location):
    api_key = '<api key>'  # Replace with your OpenWeatherMap API key
    base_url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'
    params = {'q': location, 'appid': api_key, 'units': 'metric'}

    response = requests.get(base_url, params=params)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        temperature = data['main']['temp']
        description = data['weather'][0]['description']
        response_text = f'The weather in {location} is {description} with a temperature of {temperature} degrees Celsius'
        return response_text
    else:
        return 'Weather data not available'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)

    while True:
        location = current_location  # Use the stored location
        weather_info = get_weather(location)
        print(weather_info)
        time.sleep(10)  # Adjust the interval as needed
```

Response:

> Serving Flask app "" (lazy loading)
> Enviroment: production
> WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment
> Use a production WSGI server instead
> Debug mode: off
> Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

I cannot find anything online regarding this issue, any help appreciated.

I tried to use SSH but, 1. I don't know how it works, 2. Couldn't make it work

My plan is for me to be able to say out-loud a city, have the STT code pick up what I said, transcribe it, and instead of printing it in the Pycharm console, have it be sent to the Pi where the text will be replaced into the variable "location", the Pi would then run the weather code and tell me the weather info of said city. Later, the response from the Pi telling me the weather details would be sent back to my laptop an be put into a TTS code which also works.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `location` argument in `StreamingRecognizeRequest()`. See [docs](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/speech/latest/google.cloud.speech_v1.types.StreamingRecognizeRequest)

Also you're sending every transcript, even if it's not a finalized result. It may be better to only send the final transcript to avoid incorrect or incomplete data.

Comment: New comment

I removed "location", but idk how to change the code so that it stops sending every transcript, but even if everything worked, if it sent every transcript, the Pi would tell me that it doesnt recognize what ever the code sent